# attribute Error using django Model Forms choicefield

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use ChoiceField in ModelForms follow is my code in forms.py

```
Format_Choices=[('Line Numbering','Line Numbering'),('Header Numbering','Header Numbering')]
    

class EstimateForm(forms.ModelForm):
   
   class Meta:
      model=Estimate
    
   estimateFormat=forms.ChoiceField(choices=Format_Choices,widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

this form is link with following estimate model in models.py

```
class Estimate(models.Model):
      estimateFormat=models.CharField(max_length=25,default='Line Numbering')
```

in the template  when I use

```
{{form.estimateFormat| as_crispy_field}}
```

it generate following error

```
|as_crispy_field got passed an invalid or inexistent field
```

which field should I use in models.py to make ChoiceField compliant with models.py

Comment: can you show your `views.py`?

Comment: You have to pass  choices args in  model.CharField(max_length=25,choices=Format_Choices,default='Line Numbering')

Answer (score 1):

We can add choices inside CharField as follows

```
class Estimate(models.Model):
      EstimateFormat=( ('Line Numbering','Line Numbering'),
                       ('Header Numbering','Header Numbering'),
                     )
      
      estimateFormat=models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=EstimateFormat)
```

inside ModelForms

```
class EstimateModelForm(forms.ModelForm)
      class Meta:
          model=Estimate
      fields='__all__'
```

now it will work.